# Updated React Native, can't find 'boost' dependency in Podfile

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

As mentioned in my question title, I'm trying to run `pod install` following an update to React Native 0.66, and I keep getting the following error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "boost":
  In Podfile:
    RCT-Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`) was resolved to 2021.06.28.00-v2, which depends on
      boost

    React-cxxreact (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact`) was resolved to 0.66.0, which depends on
      boost (= 1.76.0)

Specs satisfying the `boost (= 1.76.0), boost` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I've searched high-and-low for another issue referencing 'boost', but I can't find it anywhere. I've installed `boost-for-react-native` and added to my Podfile, but it doesn't seem to fix anything.

If I change my deployment target in the Podfile to `11.0` or even `14.0`, I still get the error.

This has totally stopped my project from building, so if I can get any kind of help that would be great.

Full Podfile below:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'manager' do
  # Pods for manager
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec'

  pod 'React-perflogger', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/reactperflogger'
  pod 'React-runtimeexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/runtimeexecutor'
  pod 'boost-for-react-native', :podspec => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/master/boost-for-react-native.podspec'


  # pod 'RNExtractColor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-extract-color'

  # pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

  # pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

  # pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  # pod 'react-native-view-shot', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-shot'

  target 'managerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'manager-tvOS' do
  # Pods for manager-tvOS

  target 'manager-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
  ## Fix for XCode 12.5 beta
  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
  "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

    # The following is needed to ensure the "archive" step works in XCode.
    # It removes React & Yoga from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.
    # Without this, you'd see errors when you archive like:
    # "Multiple commands produce ... libReact.a"
    # "Multiple commands produce ... libyoga.a"

    targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga)
    
    if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
      target.remove_from_project
    end

  end
end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue when I upgraded to react-native 0.66.4. Literally getting the exact error message.

I was missing the following line in my Podfile:

```
pod 'boost', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec'
```

Once I added that, I ran `pod install` and the problem was resolved!

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar issue with boost after updating react native. After the panic wore off, and some good coffee, I was able to resolve by doing the following:

1. Open the `<app_name>/ios/<app_name>.xcworkspace` file in Xcode.
2. Raise the iOS Deployment Target (in my case I only bumped to 10).
3. Product > Clean Build Folder, then Product > Run.
4. Locate the boost error in the issue navigator and identify which pod the error is listed under (in my case it was RNReanimated).
5. Update the node package related to the pod (in my case, `npm update react-native-reanimated`
6. Finally, run `pod install`

After performing those steps, I was able to get my project up and running again.